# Unusual behaviour of linux's sort command

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

On Linux shell the result of `echo -e "arrays2 2\narrays  2\narrays3 2" | sort` is

```
arrays  2
arrays2 2
arrays3 2
```

and the result of  `echo -e "arrays2 28\narrays  28\narrays3 28" | sort` is

```
arrays2 28
arrays 28
arrays3 28
```

Why in the second case the string `arrays2 28` appears on first line.
Is this a bug, or I miss something?

I tried this on RHEL4 and Ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks.

Comment: My `sort` doesn't behave like this.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Mine does. @MKo: what is your locale? Try `echo $LANG`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour is locale-dependent:

```
echo -e "arrays2 28\narrays 28\narrays3 28" | LANG=C sort
```

prints

```
arrays 28
arrays2 28
arrays3 28
```

While

```
echo -e "arrays2 28\narrays 28\narrays3 28" | LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 sort
```

prints

```
arrays2 28
arrays 28
arrays3 28
```

(Note that the locale must be installed for this to have this effect, if the locale doesn't exist, the behaviour will be the same as with `LANG=C`).

Answer (score 2):

If you change the locale from en_US.utf8 to the old default, it works the way you expect:

```
echo  -e "aaa\nfoo\narrays2 28\narrays 28\narrays3 28" | LC_ALL=C sort -
aaa
arrays 28
arrays2 28
arrays3 28
foo
```