# Column sort on multiple columns

Tags: python, sorting, ubuntu

The output I receive looks like this:

```
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type1   0.190476190476
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type1   0
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type2   0.1
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type2   -0.2
```

To get this output, I send `head -3 Tweets/FlumeData.txt | python sentimentMapper`

To sort them, `head -3 Tweets/FlumeData.txt | python sentimentMapper` | sort -k3`

This is currently sorting the data by the third column, so all the `type1`, then all the `type2`. Ideally, I'd like to sort the data alphabetically, then numerically (In other words, have all the `type1` from lowest to highest value, then all the `type2` from lowest to highest value.)

I've tried: `sort -k3 -k4n` but to no avail. How can I solve this?

**Edit: Ideal output:**

```
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type1   0
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type1   0.190476190476
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type2   -0.2
2013-08-05-Mon 10:17:00 type2   0.1
```

Comment: What is the sample output ?

Comment: I've edited the question to show original output and desired output

Comment: +1 for asking a good question and making me discovering sort `--debug` switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
LANG=C sort -k3,3 -k4,4n file
```

From `info coreutils 'sort invocation'` :

```
`-k POS1[,POS2]'
`--key=POS1[,POS2]'
     Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between
     POS1 and POS2 (or the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted),
     _inclusive_.

     Each POS has the form `F[.C][OPTS]', where F is the number of the
     field to use, and C is the number of the first character from the
     beginning of the field.  Fields and character positions are
     numbered starting with 1; a character position of zero in POS2
     indicates the field's last character.  If `.C' is omitted from
     POS1, it defaults to 1 (the beginning of the field); if omitted
     from POS2, it defaults to 0 (the end of the field).  OPTS are
     ordering options, allowing individual keys to be sorted according
     to different rules; see below for details.  Keys can span multiple
     fields.

     Example:  To sort on the second field, use `--key=2,2' (`-k 2,2').
     See below for more notes on keys and more examples.  See also the
     `--debug' option to help determine the part of the line being used
     in the sort.
```

And for `LANG=C` :

```
   (1) If you use a non-POSIX locale (e.g., by setting `LC_ALL' to
`en_US'), then `sort' may produce output that is sorted differently
than you're accustomed to.  In that case, set the `LC_ALL' environment
variable to `C'.  Note that setting only `LC_COLLATE' has two problems.
First, it is ineffective if `LC_ALL' is also set.  Second, it has
undefined behavior if `LC_CTYPE' (or `LANG', if `LC_CTYPE' is unset) is
set to an incompatible value.  For example, you get undefined behavior
if `LC_CTYPE' is `ja_JP.PCK' but `LC_COLLATE' is `en_US.UTF-8'.
```

You can take a look to this post too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868546/465183

Comment: What does LANG=C mean?

Comment: @AndrewMartin It specifies an ASCII-based sorting order, as opposed to Unicode or ISO8859-<n> or whatever your default locale settings are. As long as your input is actually ASCII, it shouldn't matter, but it might help sort out some weirdness in other cases...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work. It sorts alphabetically and positive numerics correctly, but lists negative numerics incorrectly (i.e. -0.04 before -0.1), despite the fact -0.1 is smaller than -0.04

Comment: Try the new version, it's a combo of twalberg answer and mine.

Comment: Works perfectly. Do you mind explaining a little bit about it. What do the ,3 and ,4n part do?

Comment: The `--debug` switch is really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

The `-k3` option sorts by a field defined as "starting at the first white-space character after the second field, and ending at the end of the line", which is probably not what you are intending. What you probably want is this:

```
sort -n -k3,3 -k4,4 file
```

Adding the `LANG=C` bit mentioned by sputnik may be useful, as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work. It sorts perfectly by numerics, but ignores the alphabetic sorting

Comment: @AndrewMartin I missed that your column 4 should be a numeric sort - try `-k4,4n` for that one...

Comment: Using LANG=C sort -k3 -k4,4n almost sorts it correctly, but it lists negative numbers wrong (putting -0.04 before -0.1, despite the latter being smaller)